# How to change Linux icon in dual boot?

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot, icons, linux-mint

I have just intalled Linux Mint as a second option for Windows 8. But the icon of Mint is not cool as Windows 8 in the dual boot screen. It looks like this:

[image: Windows bootloader]

How can I change the Linux icon in dual boot screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into installing GRUB 2.  You can put a variety of themes on it including your own, and it's much, much more flexible.